# Is it worth the time to follow trends and use Knockout.js or Backbone.js?

Tags: php, backbone.js, knockout.js

Me and my team will soon start the development of a new web (vtv) service.

Most of the stuff will be processed and handled through a json api but we need a decent control panel for users who want to access their data in a gui environment.

We are debating if it's worth the time to develop the control panel with a framework such as knockout or backbone or if we should just stick with our classic stack.

As a devoted Javascript fan and developer I have used both knockout and backbone for some minor apps on my spare time and I can already see how hard it is to put all these peaces together in a real production.

Is it really worth to spend extra money to follow the trends and give the user a speedier gui?

My company seems to be interested in fast bucks solely so please tell me arguments to use!

Thanks =)

Comment: If you have a modern supported stack that works well, why would you choose something new just for the sake of "following trends?"  That might be good for a resume boost, but it doesn't sound good for delivering value.

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment on Knockout, but Backbone is absolutely brilliant. It's a small framework to learn, and once you get the hang of it, you'll find it does what every framework of its kind *should* do: implement the bits that you would have implemented anyway, and think about the issues related to that that you'll realise a little down the line.

It provides a sensible event and object model system that handles the business of keeping server-side objects and client-side objects in sync and has a sensible view model with event bindings linking the two.

So to address your question, it really depends on what you're doing. If you're writing the kind of asynchronous application that uses models and gets data from an API, chances are you'll want to use the same architecture as Backbone. If you're not, you've either designed something very different and it'll be no use (so you can say 'it just doesn't fit') or you've made a mistake in your design and you'll soon need to re-write!

Answer (score 0):

Knockout or Backbone will not help you give the user a 'speedier gui'

However, it will make development easier. The frameworks impose a structure on your code - which means its easier to maintain, other people on your team can read the code and understand the flow more easily. This means you can respond to user feedback faster and give your users a positive experience

For speed of the UI itself, you should use speed optimization techniques starting with investigating the causes of slowness of the UI

In general, I'd suggest you go ahead with the framework of your choice. Only good can come out of it

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should choose a framework / library because it gives you added value or shortens development time.

If you have the time/money and want to learn to implement new technologies while writing software, that's great, go for it!

If you need to get things done quickly, use the right tool for the job.